# Where can I find code for ARMAtoMA()

Tags: r

How to find what is happening inside the function `ARMAtoMA`? I got the following results.

```
ARMAtoMA
#function (ar = numeric(), ma = numeric(), lag.max) 
#.Call(C_ARMAtoMA, as.double(ar), as.double(ma), as.integer(lag.max))
#<bytecode: 0x000000001a5f5700>
#<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in R's source file:

```
R-<version>/src/library/stats/src/pacf.c
```

- We find inside `R-<version>/src/library/stats/` because it is from `stats` package;
- We find in `R-<version>/src/library/stats/src` because it is the C code;
- Finally, there are multiple `.c` files under `R-<version>/src/library/stats/src`. If you search "ARMAtoMA" in those files, you can locate the `pacf.c`.

I make a copy for you here:

```
SEXP ARMAtoMA(SEXP ar, SEXP ma, SEXP lag_max)
  {
    int i, j, p = LENGTH(ar), q = LENGTH(ma), m = asInteger(lag_max);
    double *phi = REAL(ar), *theta = REAL(ma), *psi, tmp;
    SEXP res;

    if(m <= 0 || m == NA_INTEGER)
    error(_("invalid value of lag.max"));
    PROTECT(res = allocVector(REALSXP, m));
    psi = REAL(res);
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    tmp = (i < q) ? theta[i] : 0.0;
    for(j = 0; j < min(i+1, p); j++)
        tmp += phi[j] * ((i-j-1 >= 0) ? psi[i-j-1] : 1.0);
    psi[i] = tmp;
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return res;
}
```